# localhost asp.net mvc app doesn't works fine when i insert data

Tags: asp.net

```
using (OurDbContext db = new OurDbContext())
{
    var candidate = new Details()
    {
        Name = register.Name,
        Email = register.Email,
        Mobile = register.Mobile,
        ApplyFor = register.ApplyFor,
        Resume = SaveTo(file)
    };

    db.Detail.Add(candidate);
    returnValue = db.SaveChanges();
}
```

This code runs correctly and insert data on server by local machine  but when i use this code to insert data on remote server it does not work

Comment: What things does not work in remote machine after deployment? Please explain in detail, also include all errors if you found any.

Comment: data doesn't insert in on remote server,if application run from server Actually i applied some conditions on the value return by SaveChanges() but SaveChanges MEthod is returning 0 always and data is not able to insert in data base

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the error.

Comment: actually i captured the error and thanks for your reply